# Fill interpolated values between two adjacent row values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm looking to turn a pandas dataframe from this (only where foo==A):

```
year foo amount
1998 A   0.0
1999 A   0.6
```

to something like this:

```
year month foo amount
1998 1     A   0.0
1998 2     A   0.05
1998 3     A   0.1
1998 4     A   0.15
1998 5     A   0.2
1998 6     A   0.25
1998 7     A   0.3
1998 8     A   0.35
1998 9     A   0.4
1998 10    A   0.45
1998 11    A   0.5
1998 12    A   0.55
1999 1     A   0.6
```

Additionally (next step), I might want to center the target value at middle of the year with smooth (linear) interpolation between adjacent years. e.g. the "amount" is becoming the exact value for June (6) and between that the amount value is interpolated between years.

```
year foo amount
2000 A   0.6
2001 A   1.0
2002 A   0.0
2003 A   0.8
```

towards

```
year month foo amount
2000 1     A   0.0
2000 2     A   0.1
2000 3     A   0.2
...
2000 6     A   0.6      // exact value
2000 7     A   0.633   
...  
2001 4     A   0.9333
2001 5     A   0.9667
2001 6     A   1.0     // exact value
2001 7     A   0.91667
2001 8     A   0.8333
...
2002 6     A   0.0  // exact value
...
```

any ideas?

Comment: `pandas` has a really nice interpolation/resampling implemented. Best approach would be to fill the index of the DataFrame with the years as a datetime index and then resample the DataFrame with: `df.resample('1m').interpolate()`. But this will only work if you want to have a datetime index.

Comment: thanks. interpolate and resample almost got me there, but I struggle a bit with the datetime index - the 'year' might contain duplicate entries for different values of 'foo' ...

Comment: You can have different rows for different values of `foo`.